# Find orthogonal state for random 7 qubit state

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming, qutip

I have a system that generates a random 7 qubit state and I need a method to always find the orthogonal state.

I'm currently using python and qutip for this, representing this 7 qubit state by a 128-dimensional vector.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you divide the entire $7$-qubit Hilbert space into two subspaces: the one spanned by your state (let's call the state $|\psi\rangle$), let's call that subspace $W$, and it's orthogonal complement $V = W^{\perp}$. You want *any* vector from $V$, because this will by definition be orthogonal.

We know that $P_{V}$ + $P_{W} = I$, with $P_{V}$ and $P_{W}$ being the projectors upon the $V$ and $W$ subspaces. Since $P_{W} = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, we can easily calculate $P_{V}$:

$$
P_{V} = I - |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|.
$$
We can let this projection matrix act on virtually *any* state to obtain a state orthogonal on $|\psi\rangle$, lets use the $0$ vector $|00....0\rangle$. An orthogonal state $|\psi^{\perp}\rangle$ to $|\psi\rangle$ is thus:

$$
|\psi^{\perp}\rangle = P_{V}|00...0\rangle = (I - |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)|00...0\rangle = |00...0\rangle - \langle\psi|00...0\rangle|\psi\rangle
$$

which is more or less the Gram-Schmidt process.

Note that you can use (almost) *any* state instead of $|00...0\rangle$; the only state that you *cannot* use is $|\psi\rangle$ itself.

In python, this becomes something like:

`from numpy import zeros_like, inner`

`zeros_vect = zeros_like(psi_orig)`

`psi_orth = zeros_vect - inner(zeros_vect,psi_orig).conj()*psi_orig`